# What is an adjective synonym for "discretion" or "up to you?"

Tags: word-usage, synonyms

This has been bothering me for some time, and I apologize for any mistakes here.

What I'm looking for is another word for discretion without possession. It's almost like saying the phrase "up to you".

Example:

> I don't care about the color of the car, so that is [your decision/up to you].
>
> What you choose to wear is completely [your decision/up to you].

I could say "That is your discretion" but I'm looking for an adjective. I was thinking of the word **optional** but that almost implies that the object is unnecessary.

Comment: How about, "It's your choice."?  (BTW - "I don't care *for* the color of the car" means you don't like the color of the car.  I think you meant "I don't care *about* the color of the car.".)

Comment: Thank you, didn't catch that. Ha. Also, I'm thinking more for an adjective in a way that "arbitrary" can be used for "His meal times are completely random."

Comment: The term is not "That is your discretion" but "at your discretion" (e.g. "Come at your discretion" — in other words, "come if you think it is wise / safe / convenient" [depending on the context]); also "up to your discretion" (e.g. "Whether you come today or tomorrow is up to your discretion" — in other words, "come when you think it is most convenient or appropriate"). There is some overlap in usage.

Comment: From AHDEL: **discretionary** adj. 1. Left to or regulated by one's own discretion or judgment. General reference.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you could use the adjective *volitional*, if you were feeling especially high-toned. Here is the definition of *volition* in *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003):

> **volition** *n* (1615) **1 :** an act of making a choice or decision; *also* **:** a choice or decision made **2 :** the power of choosing or determining : WILL —**volitional** *adj*

But the more common adjective these days is surely the one that Edwin Ashworh recommends in a comment above: *discretionary*. Again, the *Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary*'s definition:

> **discretionary** *adj* (1698) **1 :** left to discretion : exercised at one's own discretion [where *discretion* means "individual choice or judgment"] **2 :** available for discretionary use

Definition 1 of *discretionary* is the relevant one for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to find a word or phrase that fits your examples. I can suggest the following:

For your first sentence, you could use **"at random"**

> - "at random" - without definite aim, direction, rule, or method. - [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/at+random?show=0&t=1421881227)

- "I don't care about the color, just choose at random."
- "We tasted the wines at random and then rated each."
- "Choose a card at random from the deck."

For your second sentence, I suggest **"personal"**

> - "personal" (adj) "relating to a particular person" - [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/personal)

- "Whatever you choose to wear is completely personal."

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [immaterial](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/immaterial)?

> Unimportant under the circumstances; irrelevant: *the difference in our
>   ages is immaterial*